# Python3 - Pandas Resample function

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("temp.data",sep=';')

data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date']+' '+data['Time'])
del data['Time']
data.rename(columns={'Date':'TimeStamp'}, inplace=True)

data = data.reset_index()
data['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TimeStamp'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
data['num'] = pd.to_numeric(data['num'])
data = data.resample('1M')
```

Error: 
"**TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'**". 
Sample data (Original data has 200 thousand rows, with no missing values):

```
17/12/2006;01:58:00;3.600
17/12/2006;01:59:00;2.098
17/12/2006;02:00:00;1.334
17/12/2006;02:01:00;4.362
17/12/2006;02:02:00;1.258
17/12/2006;02:03:00;2.448
17/12/2006;02:04:00;5.426
17/12/2006;02:05:00;9.704
```

Comment: I have even played around with the date format: 
format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' and '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' both did not work. It's the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the error, when trying to resample, you have a RangeIndex, which is just consecutive integers, while you need one that represents points in time.

Adding

```
data.set_index('TimeStamp', inplace=True)
```

before you resample will set your `'TimeStamp'` column as the index. You can also do away with

```
data = data.reset_index()
```

unless you want an extra column labeled 'index' floating around.